# Telerik - placing JavaScript file includes at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, performance, telerik

It is [recommended that JavaScript files be included on the bottom](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) of the page. I'm using Telerik Rad Ajax controls that emit JavaScript includes on top of the page. Is there a way to force it to emit JavaScript includes at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Why do you say "It is recommended that js files be included on the bottom of the page. "?

Comment: by yahoo best practices...http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: That viewpoint is very controversial because - for instance - this only creates the appearance of fast rendering, and can create side-effect problems of appearing to hang where a script load is unusually long or many scripts are stacked at the EOF. There are other ways to avoid script blocking, and head inlined scripts are fine.

Comment: can you suggest some "other ways to avoid script blocking"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place your **RadAjaxManager** as the last control in your markup, it will emit the JavaScript at the bottom of the page.

However as far as the placement of the included references to the scriptresource.axd(s). There's no setting to change that.

Comment: also if you try to add javascript in codebehind use RegisterStartupScript function, which will put your js file right before closing form tag </form>.

Answer (score 1):

A solution to this problem may be to use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) to load the script asynchronously like this:

```
$(function () {
  $.getScript("script.js", function () { // You may skip the second argument
    alert("Done loading");
  });
});
```

You may wait a while too like this:

```
$(function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $.getScript("script.js");
  }, 500);
});
```